# Skeletal muscles in clam

Tags: physiology, muscles

Although skeletal muscle fatigues fairly rapidly, clams have a protein called paramyosin that allows them to sustain contractions for up to a month. What might be the role of paramyosin at the molecular or cellular level, which results in this peculiarity?

Comment: This appears to be a homework question, which is often frowned-upon without prior research. Where have you looked so far?

Comment: Without proper background knowledge I'd say that that's for keeping the shell closed.

Comment: actually this is an 'Scientific Enquiry'- type question in "Biology By Campbell & Reece"...

Answer (score 5):

Older papers initially presumed that it was part of a [mechanism called "catch"](http://physrev.physiology.org/content/56/4/829.long) in invertebrates like molluscs which is a "sustained contraction."  However, paramyosin was also found in [insects](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0305049176903102).  There is a [very detailed review on invertebrate muscle from 2008](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18616971) that you should read through (or, you know, search through) points out that recent evidence has shown that paramyosin is **not** involved in catch; that review also has this to say on the subject (emphasis added):

> Furthermore, paramyosin’s presence in almost **every invertebrate muscle** (including those with relatively small thick filaments) suggests that paramyosin should **not be considered a ‘special’ molecule whose presence needs explanation**. Paramyosin is instead an everyday constituent of invertebrate muscles, similar, for instance, to the giant sarcomere associated proteins (see Hooper and Thuma, 2005). Indeed, a more salient question might be **why vertebrates do not have paramyosin**.

Comment: Following through; OP's questions seems poorly posed. Indeed, sustained contraction is nothing special. That's what muscle tone *is*.

Comment: From an anthropocentric position, though, it's a fair question, although as I point out the better question is why we can't contract consistently but many invertebrates can.

Comment: Yeah I'm confused by your point. Paramyosin is *not* involved in catch. Contracting consistently isn't difficult if you think about rigor tonus.